# Terminology: In OOP, what is it called when you have an object or record that uses "joined" data from a lookup table or gateway?

Tags: oop, terminology

Lets say you have an object, `User` that comes from a table called `user`, and that object has a property called `primaryAddress`.  `primaryAddress` is a foreign key to a reference table or list of addresses in an `Address` table.

When building the `User` object, you can associate properties of the address based on the foreign key/primary key relationship.  For example, I can associate the properties `streetAddress`, `city`, `state`, `postalCode`, etc.. simply because I can join the data from `User` to `Address`.

[image: sql model]

In a relational database you get this data usually though a join like `INNER JOIN` or `OUTER JOIN`. However, I'm not sure what this type of relationship is called in object oriented programming (OOP) when an object "obtains" data from another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OOP/OOD the closest thing you'd have is probably [aggregation or composition](https://atomicobject.com/resources/oo-programming/object-oriented-aggregation) - you wouldn't refer to the address by ID but rather have a non-owning reference (in case a particular address could be used by multiple people, e.g. families), or an owning reference (in case there's always a 1-1 relationship between a person and their particular address in the db).

Comment: Thank you! Knowing the proper term will help me in further researching this topic.  

If I understand your response properly, regardless of whether the relationship is an aggregate or composition, when assembling the `User` object you could include an instance of an `Address` object inside it, right?

Comment: @DaveL - In OOA/OOD, these are called associations and have a completely different meaning from the relational model. An OO association establishes how classes *collaborate* in terms of sharing knowledge or delegating behaviour whereas a relational join defines how two sets of data are, well, related. If you are doing proper OO, you should avoid composition and aggregation at all costs because they lead you to think in terms of "this class is composed of this, this, and that" or "this class owns this and that". In OO, your goal is to make classes *collaborate* -- not *own* each other.